how I can increase request per second in laravel octane?
I Dockerized a Laravel application that uses MySQL and Redis (MySQL runs on my host and Redis in a container). When I use Locust for load testing, after the requests per second (RPS) reach 140, any additional requests start to fail. For example, if the RPS reaches 500, only 140 requests succeed, and 360 requests fail.
In another test with loader.io with 6000 users per minute, everything works fine. However, when I increase the users to more than 6000, most of the requests time out.
I have a VM with this configuration (it doesn't use all my resources at all):
host : ubuntu 22.04
RAM: 60 GB
CPU: 47 cores
Here is my Dockerfile:

FROM php:8.2-fpm as php

# Set environment variables
ENV PHP_OPCACHE_ENABLE=1
ENV PHP_OPCACHE_ENABLE_CLI=0
ENV PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMP=0
ENV PHP_OPCACHE_REVALIDATE_FREQ=0

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    libpq-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    git \
    supervisor \
    libaio1 \
    libpcre3-dev

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    mysqli \
    pdo \
    pdo_mysql \
    bcmath \
    curl \
    opcache \
    mbstring \
    gd \
    pcntl

# Install Swoole extension
RUN pecl install swoole && docker-php-ext-enable swoole

# Copy composer executable
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer


# Set working directory to /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy files from current folder to container current folder (set in workdir)
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . .

# Install Laravel Octane
RUN composer require laravel/octane --dev

# Create a script to run octane install in non-interactive mode
RUN echo 'php artisan octane:install --server="swoole"' > install_octane.sh && \
    chmod +x install_octane.sh && \
    ./install_octane.sh

RUN php artisan vendor:publish --tag=octane-config

# Create laravel caching folders
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/framework/{cache,testing,sessions,views}
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/resources/views

# Fix files ownership
RUN chown -R www-data /var/www/storage \
    && chown -R www-data /var/www/storage/framework \
    && chown -R www-data /var/www/storage/framework/sessions \
    && chown -R www-data /var/www/resources/views

# Set correct permission
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/storage \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/storage/logs \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/storage/framework \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/storage/framework/sessions \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/bootstrap \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/resources/views


# Adjust user permission & group
RUN usermod --uid 1000 www-data \
    && groupmod --gid 1001 www-data

# Run the entrypoint file
ENTRYPOINT [ "docker/entrypoint2.sh" ]

My docker compose file
version: "3.8"
services:

    # PHP Service
    php:
        image: laravel.octan.optimizer:3

        environment:
          APP_NAME: appname
          APP_ENV: local
          APP_KEY: 
          APP_DEBUG: "false"
          LOG_CHANNEL: stack
          LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL: "null"
          LOG_LEVEL: debug
          DB_CONNECTION: mysql
          DB_HOST: [HOST_IP]
          DB_PORT: 3306
          DB_DATABASE: dbname
          DB_USERNAME: root
          DB_PASSWORD: 123
          SMSIR_API_KEY: KfENDZ4xfjepFKKJL64peTEzfuJUxX9j6trxklaZTDDBC4v2eYBULibyMSAaDHpx
          SMSIR_LINE_NUMBER: 30007732903708
          REDIS_HOST: [HOST_IP]
          REDIS_PASSWORD: null
          REDIS_PORT: 6379
          CONTAINER_ROLE: app

        working_dir: /var/www
        
        ports:
          - 6001:6001
          - 8000:8000

I tried increasing MySQL's max_connections to 100,000, but it doesn't increase beyond 9190. This was not very effective as my RPS only increased from 120 to 140.
I tried this with another sample Laravel application using:
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
The new application can't handle more than 140 RPS; beyond that, more requests fail.
What could be the problem and how can I find a solution? I also tried Dockerizing with PHP-FPM and Nginx, but RPS above 110 fails.
I expected the requests per second to reach 500 and to handle more than 15,000 concurrent users per minute.

what does your entrypoint file do? Did you run php artisan optimize in the entrypoint? If not, try that and let us know if there's any improvement.

this is mu entrypoint ->
php artisan optimize
php artisan octane:start --server=swoole --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000 --env=.env
I added php artisan optimize, but no improvement happened.

Try to add workers count and test it . if you not specify workers count then automatically it tasks the CPU core count .
PHP artisan octane:start --workers=100

